# Updating a number on a webpage without reloading using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want a progress bar to display a random number every second , this is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<progress id="bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>

<script>
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
setInterval(function(){ bar.value = {{value}}; }, 1000);
</script>
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import random
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html',value=random.randrange(0, 100))

app.run(host="192.168.178.50", port=4999)
```

But it only updates once I reload the page.

Comment: You can also use javascript  to update a number with [math.random](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp)

Comment: @Palomar is [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532028/12446721) working for you. If it solves your issue. Then don't forget to mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: @Palomar if you like my effort you can upvote my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :D, until now I couldnt upvote things because of reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajax` it is simple to use, you can change this in HTML code,

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/rand",
      type: "get",
      success: function(response) {
        bar.value = response;
       },
      error: function(xhr) {
          //Handel error
      }
    }); 
}, 1000);
</script>
```

And this for python:

```
@app.route("/rand")
def random_number():
    return f"{random.randrange(0, 100)}"
```

We are sending request to servers every second and get random number. And change value of bar.